# Cuadro de Alerta en ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quisiera preguntar si en `ASP.NET` `C#` se puede hacer un `alert` similar al que se puede realizar en *Windows Form* con la sentencia `MessageBox`. Que si presiono `Si` hace algo y si presiono `No` se cancela.

Comment: `Windows form` es para sistemas `Desktop` , para web hay muchas `librerias` para mostrar alertas personalizadas. y no tendría  que ver con ASP en sí , más bien con lado del cliente , `Javascript` , `Tostr` por ejemplo

Comment: @dev.Joel como que librerías se puede implementar en asp.net c# en el codehebind

Answer (score 1):

Para estos casos lo mejor es programarlo de lado de cliente con Javascript (como te comentan).

Como hablas de hacerlo en el codebehind entiendo que desarrollas con Web Forms y que preferirías hacerlo con algún control de servidor.
Podrías utilizar el [ModalPopup](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) del [Ajax Control Toolkit](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit/). Es gratuito y te da la funcionalidad que buscas.

Comment: hey bro :D buen día, podrías agregar un ejemplo de código por favor? De esta manera aumentas la calidad de tu respuesta :D Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Se puede agregar un `OnClientClick` a tu botón desde el html y llama la función:

```
OnClientClick="Aviso()" 

function Aviso()
{
    confirm("Press a button!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTitlePopUp" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <img src="res/img1.png" width="174" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->

        <button type="button" style="display: none;" id="btnShowPopup" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            Launch demo modal
        </button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ShowPopup() {
                $("#btnShowPopup").click();
            }
        </script>
```

c# code here

```
 if (code == true)//se inserto
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
                        this.lblTitlePopUp.Text = "Muy bien";
                        this.lblMessage.Text = "Muy bien, ya te encuentras inscrito en nuestra base de datos ahora pueden iniciar sesión.";
                    }
                    else //problemas al insertar
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
                        this.lblTitlePopUp.Text = "Algo salio mal";
                        this.lblMessage.Text = "Tu registro no ha podido llevarse a cabo debido a que estamos presentando errores en nuestros servidores. Te sugerimos volver a intentarlo más tarde.";
                    }
```

Crea tus controles para que los puedas ejecutar del lado del servidor agregando el tag de runat="Server". y Dentro de el moodal puedes colocar los controles que quieras.